# Memory Leak due to CTFontRef

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, ctfontref

I am generating a PDF using the below detail , in Instrument i am getting memory leak, can any one have idea why the instruments point to the `CTFontRef` to 100 perc leak.?

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                                 initWithString:textToDraw] autorelease];   
CTFontRef helveticaBold = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica-Bold"), 8.0, NULL);

[string addAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName
                       value:(id)helveticaBold
                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming ARC):

```
[string addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName
               value:CFBridgingRelease(helveticaBold)
               range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Comment: sorry i wasn't using ARC :( ,but releasing the CTfontRef was a help